# Insert Formulas Into Blank Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code to insert a user-defined number of blank rows, and it works well.  What I need to add to the code is a way to insert formulas in the first blank rows after they have been inserted.  Specifically, I need to add the values in the last row of data in columns J+T, K+U, L+V, M+W, N+T, O+U, P+W, Q+U, R+W, and S+V into each blank row inserted.

If it helps, the VBA code for inserting the blank rows is below:

```
Dim NumRowsToInsert, FirstRow As Long
Dim RowIncrement As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastEvenlyDivisibleRow
Dim i As Long

Do
FirstRow = InputBox("Please indicate at which row you want to start.")
Loop Until IsNumeric(FirstRow) 
NumRowsToInsert = InputBox("How many rows would you like to insert _
between each row of data?")
Do
Loop Until IsNumeric(NumRowsToInsert)
RowIncrement = InputBox("How many rows of data between line inserts?")
Do
Loop Until IsNumeric(RowIncrement)
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = Int(LastRow / RowIncrement) * RowIncrement
If LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = LastEvenlyDivisibleRow To FirstRow Step -RowIncrement
    .Range(i & ":" & i + (NumRowsToInsert - 1)).Insert xlShiftDown
Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your code that tries to insert the formulas?

Answer (score 0):

To add a formula to a cell you would do something to this effect

```
'this makes the value of Row 20 Column 1 the sum of B2 through B10
Sheets(1).Cells(20, 1).Formula = "=Sum(B2:B10)"
```

Comment: I probably didn't explain myself well enough in my original post.  What the VBA code above does is create multiple rows of data separated by empty rows (sometimes multiple empty rows).  What I need the VBA code to do is insert the formulas in the first empty row after each row of data.  The columns I need to add are listed above.  I hope this paints a better picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.